# Scraping with BeautifulSoup [Help]

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I follow a course to learn Python and I try to do some scraping, however I have some difficulties with my program (I use PyCharm):

```
import urllib2

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = urllib2.urlopen(raw_input("Enter - "))

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")

tags = soup("span")

total = []

for tag in tags:

    total.append(int(tag))

print sum(total)
print len(total)
```

The problem is when I run the code, the page which I want to scrap opens but the code does not run i.e. I don't have the sum and the length of my list

Comment: What's the page you're trying to scrape?

Comment: `tag` is a `Tag` object, you can't turn it to int. You should use `int(tag.text)` or some other attribute.

Comment: I think the `soup("span")` is wrong, thus I suspect tags may be empty. You should make sure the path is right to get anything for later processing.

Comment: I try with http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_35201.html The goal is to print the sum of all numbers and the "numbers" of numbers. I tried with : total.append(int(tag.text)) however this is the same result

Comment: Your import statement is wrong. Use: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Thank u all ! I delete BeautifulSoup and re install it...  Now it works correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean by "numbers" of numbers? Check it out, if this is what you meant:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

response = requests.get("http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_35201.html").text
tree = html.fromstring(response)
title = [item.text for item in tree.cssselect(".comments")]
for x in range(len(title)):
    print("{} {}".format(x+1,title[x]))
```

Partial result:

```
1 97
2 91
3 88
4 87
5 87
6 86
```